# AleaGPU Dynamic Parallelism in F#? How?

Tags: f#, aleagpu, dynamic-parallelism

This might be a simple question, but I have not been able to find any references to this topic: **How do I launch a kernel from within another kernel?**. The only relevant example I came across is the post:([Does Alea GPU support dynamic parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149801/does-alea-gpu-support-dynamic-parallelism/46173178)), which presents an example in C#.

Given that F# utilizes Code Quotation, I am assuming there is a direct way to perform this operation that I just cannot find.

Please advise, or point me to a relevant resource.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.